# Existence of only ONE solution to this modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have to proof:

If $(a, m) = 1,$ then $ax\equiv{b}\pmod{m}$ has ONE solution in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

I did the following:

We have: $ax\equiv{b}\pmod{m}$. It follows: $b = ax + nm$, with $n$ being any integer. If $(a, m) = 1,$ it follows that $1|(ax + nm)$. But I got stuck and I don't know how to conclude that there's only ONE solution or if I even went on the right path.

Thanks for reading and helping.

EDIT:

After reading your comments I got here:

First, since we have $(a,m)=1$ then we have the linear expression: $ax + mn = 1$ where $mn$ can be interpreted as the residue and it is unique given the linear combination. Then, we can state: $$ax \equiv 1 \pmod{mn}$$

The expression means that $mn |(1-ax)$, and since $mn$ is unique, it follows that it has only one solution.

Thanks again for reading and correcting me.

Comment: You probably mean one solution in $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$. Otherwise this is untrue.

Comment: Thanks, you were right and it was corrected

Comment: No, it was not corrected. It is still incorrect.

Comment: What you need to show is that if $x$ is a solution and $x'$ is another solution, then $x\equiv x' \pmod m$. Use the fact that $a$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $m$, which follows from $(a,m)=1$.

Comment: Look at the numbers $a\cdot 0,a\cdot1,a\cdot 2,...,a\cdot (m-1)$. If two of them $a\cdot i$ and $a\cdot j$ leave the same remainder modulo $m$, then $a(i-j)$ is divisible by $m$. Since $(a,m)=1$, it follows that $i-j$ is divisible by $m$. Therefore $i=j$. Hence all the numbers $a\cdot 0,a\cdot1,a\cdot 2,...,a\cdot (m-1)$ leave different remainders modulo $m$. There are only $m$ different remainders modulo $m$. So, one of those numbers leave the remainder of $b$.

Comment: " It follows: b=ax+nm, with n being any integer."  No.  It follows that $b =ax +nm$ for *some* integer.  It obviously isn't true for more than one integer $n$, much less *any* integer.

Comment: Are you familiar with Bezout's lemma.  It tell you there are some $j,k$ so that $aj + bk = 1$.  Can you use that to prove there is at least one solution? Then if there are two solutions can you see why $ax - ay\equiv 0\pmod b$ but $x\not \equiv y\pmod b$ is impossible?